# Efficient way to perform various String operations

Tags: java, regex, string, stringbuilder

I have a Script in which i have to extract string from strings, get the last index, get nth character in a string, comparisons, string contains a string or not etc etc. I would like to know the best method/ practice to do such operations on strings in java. Should i use `StringBuilder` all the time to perform the above operations. In few cases i have used `regular expressions` to find strings.
So what should i use?
Scenario is : loads of comparisons and indexes have to found. Thanks.!

---

example :

```
    String name = "application/octet-stream; name=\"2012-04-20.tar.gz\""; // get 2012-04-20.tar.gz
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

---

```
    String date = " Number 4, December 2013";
    String year = date.substring(date.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
    String month = date.substring(date.indexOf(',')+2,date.indexOf(" ",date.indexOf(',')+2 ));
    date = year+getMonth(month)+"01";
    System.out.println(date);
```

---

Like above, many other extraction of string within string.

Comment: Is it always the same format for a particular application? Have you considered StringTokenizer? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: no ! there are other 4 5 formats as well. And these formats are processed thousands of times!
no, i havent considered string tokenizer. Would that help increasing the efficiency ?

Comment: its says : `StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.`

Answer (score 1):

When you deal with large amount of String object use String `intern` function wisely to conserve heap space and eliminate object creation overhead. refer [here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/save-memory-by-using-string-intern-in-java/) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not manipulating the strings, you can use String or StringUtils instead of StringBuilder

Answer (score 0):

All of these operations can be done with the String class, see below for the methods you should use.

> extract string from strings

[String.substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

> get the last index

[String.length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) -1

> the last character

s.charAt(s.length()-1);

> get nth character in a string

[String.charAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)

> comparisons

[String.compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)

> string contains a string or not

[String.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)
You can also use String.toLowerCase() on both if necessary

Comment: I have used all above methods. I want to know should i use all the above operations? or there is any other efficient method?

Comment: There are mathematical lower bounds to the time efficiency of these operations, I would assume the built in String methods operate quite close to optimal.